# WebdriverIO cannot get value for input?

Tags: javascript, selenium, safari, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am automating tests for a web application just for safari....
  But I am having troubles with it. It seems webdriverIO works not very well with safari.
  My environment is: 
  wdio: v4.13.1
  node: v10.8.0

I try to get the value of an input field

```
const value = browser.getValue('input.xxxxxxxxx')
```

but I got exception

```
The command 'GET /session/E5218F3F-7FE1-43D5-A231-A4B8CCB2C599/element/node-807A67A6-E0E8-4AD7-A505-9ED62ECD6FE6/property/value' was not found.
running safari
Error: The command 'GET /session/E5218F3F-7FE1-43D5-A231-A4B8CCB2C599/element/node-807A67A6-E0E8-4AD7-A505-9ED62ECD6FE6/property/value' was not found.
at elementIdProperty("node-807A67A6-E0E8-4AD7-A505-9ED62ECD6FE6", "value") - getValue.js:35:54
```

However, this runs perfectly if I use Chrome.
I also tried a bit more tacky way like

```
const value = browser.execute("document.querySelector('input.xxxxxxxx')")
console.log(value)
// gives me this
{ sessionId: '40DD4190-CB6D-4188-962F-9059D96C0441',
value: null,
_status: 0 }
```

Cannot find a workaround for this. Anyone can help with this?

I also find that click is also not working for safari. It will complain that the element is not visible but the element is obviously visible over there.
My workaround for that is

```
browser.execute("document.querySelector('.popup-menu-items li).click()")
```

In chrome I don't need to do this dirty workaround.
Testing in safari with webdriverIO is really painful.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with selenium, not webdriverio.

Searching quickly on google gave me this official setup page:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/testing_with_webdriver_in_safari

If that doesn't do it, I believe you should investigate more on the selenium side.

Answer (score 0):

I spent way too much time looking into this yesterday because I got the same error when running on Safari with wdio v4.13.2

The error message is quite correct, there is no command:

```
GET /session/:sessionId/element/:id/property/:name
```

What we actually want to do is this:

```
GET /session/:sessionId/element/:id/attribute/:name
```

I found some docs listing which calls that could be made [here](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md)

If you look at the function `getValue` in webdriverio it calls a function of its own called `elementIdProperty` which makes the request to the url `wd/hub/session/"sessionId"/element/"elementId"/property/value` mentioned above. However, there is a conditional statement in the function, saying if it is an unknown command it should make a call to another function called `elementIdAttribute` which makes a request to the correct url, ending with `/attribute/value`. My guess is that when you run it in Chrome it recognises the response of an unknown command, while when you run it in Safari it doesn't. When I tried making the requests manually in the a browser the responses looked different. All this was very frustrating to find out and hard to troubleshoot.

My workaround is to simply use the function `getAttribute` from webdriverio directly, like so:

```
const value = browser.getAttribute(selector, 'value');
```

Then we can see if they'll fix it in a later version of webdriverio.